# Positioning and Overflow with CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3SH/

This is what i wanted to do:

1. On the right element, I'd like the "Close" text to be vertically centered.
2. On the main element, I'd like the lorem text to not overflow into the right.

Note the outer element has fixed position on purpose.  Here's what I've tried:

- Making the p elements inline-blocks or otherwise, didn't make a difference.
- Making the right element a table-cell but it still didn't vertically center.
- Putting a hidden overflow on any/all of the elements with no luck.

Here's some CSS to satisfy the submission parser:

```
#panel-notice > p#close {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#panel-notice > p#message {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

EDIT: I should note, in case it wasn't clear, that the lorem text could be any height including one line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3SH/3/

Comment: @NoobEditor: Thanks, that's very close but the "close" isn't centered for me.  I'm sure I can figure it out from here though.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#panel-notice {display:table}

#panel-notice > p#close {display:table-cell; float:right;}
```

remove `position:absolute` and just put `#panel-notice > p#close` after `p#message` in html:)

Comment: I believe I followed your directions but it didn't work, at least, it didn't come out as I described.  If you get the time could you modify the fiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: @Anrdrei: Thanks, seems the trick was to make the outer container a display:table.  I've marked your answer as the solution, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position: absolute;` width the `#close` div so use `top:50%` to make it center.
and in second point you should have to specify the with to the #message div to overcome overflow issue

Here's the demo
        [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/4PPj4/2/)

Comment: The centering didn't really work because 50% isn't really center as you have to account for the text offset.  Also, I'd prefer not set a width on the message (but specifying a width on the close is probably acceptable).  Thanks for the help!